# using nested loops in order to group data in a csv

Tags: python

I am looping through lines of a csv in order to extract and transform data.

the csv looks like this:

```
alex, blue, 3
alex, blue, 4
liza, green, 2
alex, red, 4
alex, orange, 3
liza, blue, 2
liza, blue, 21
liza, yellow, 23
```

the result i want from the above are 2 files:

**alex file**

```
<blue>3, 4</blue>
<red>4</red>
<orange>3</orange>
```

**liza file**

```
<green>2</green>
<blue>2,21</blue>
<yellow>23</yellow>
```

i am not looking for you to solve this problem for me, but i am just looking for your guidance. i dont need help with the xml part, i would just like help on the LOGIC part.

thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred datastructure here (assuming order of names and colours isn't important!) would be a nested `defaultdict`.  The usual usage is something like this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> d['blue'].append(3)
>>> d['blue'].append(4)
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'blue': [3, 4]})
```

But we can also go one level deeper:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1004bf9b0>, {})
>>> d['alex']['blue'].append(3)
>>> d['alex']['blue'].append(4)
>>> d['liza']['green'].append(2)
>>> d
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x1004bf9b0>, {'liza': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'green': [2]}), 'alex': defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'blue': [3, 4]})})
>>> d.keys()
['liza', 'alex']
>>> d['alex'].keys()
['blue']
>>> d['alex']['blue']
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a dictionary of lists? Every time something not found in the dictionary is encountered, an list for that element is added to the dictionary. Then you can just append repeat elements into the lists inside the dictionary.

The resulting structure for your example input would be:

```
alex dictionary:
{
   "blue" : [3,4],
   "red": [4],
   "orange": [3]
}

liza dictionary:
{
   "green" : [2],
   "blue": [2,21],
   "yellow": [23]
}
```

Of course you could further abstract away liza and alex with another dictionary layer.

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be best to maintain a series of lists (one for each color) for both the alex file and the liza file, since you don't know how many entries of each color you'll have. So essentially, you would loop through the csv, determine if you're dealing with alex or liza (first piece of info), determine the color (second piece of info), and append the integer value (third piece of info) to the appropriate list. Once you finish going through the file, it shouldn't be difficult to create the two output files.

Edit: Of course, if you don't know which colors you will encounter or will encounter a high number of colors, it would probably be wisest to use the dictionary approach that some other answers have suggested.

Comment: Unless you don't know exactly which colors you'll encounter?